# Open URL in default browser (Chromium) from terminal and give browser focus

Tags: command-line, scripts, browser

I am trying to open an URL from the terminal window in my default browser which is Chromium:

```
$ xdg-open 'https://www.google.no/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:askubuntu.com+xdg-open' >/dev/null
```

This will open the URL in a new tab in Chromium browser, but focus is still in the terminal window. How can I also bring Chromium browser to the front of my desktop, and give it focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep your command as is and change the way applications are getting automatic focus by changing the following settings.

Open a terminal and type:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 0
```

To restore the initial behaviour:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 1
```