# Windows open second from top when I use hotkeys

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I like using assigned keyboard shortcuts (hotkeys) to open commonly used applications. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> opens Firefox for me. When I do it this way, it opens just below the currently active window. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
Just install Compiz Config Manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then open it and go to **General Options > Focus and Raise Behaviour**
Under **Focus prevention level** select **off**.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I would however prefer to do it without installing  `compizconfig-settings-manager`. There are several other options, like: http://askubuntu.com/a/598619/72216